# How do I update a SQL table to strip away the left 3 characters in a 9 character string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I have a table with values like this in columnA:

```
ColumnA
800
800602041
800602044
800602050
800602057
800602093
800602099
800602131
800602132
800602133
```

I need to strip away the leading 800 but leave the rest of the numbers intact.  I tried doing an update with wildcards but it failed. I have several tables with thousands of records that need this correction.

The result would look like this:

```
ColumnA
800
602041
602044
602050
602057
602093
602099
602131
602132
602133
```

I cannot lose the single 800 record which is why I was trying an update query with wildcards. I only want to update the rows with a 9 digit value that begins with 800.

Comment: Tag you question with the database you are using.

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. Are there any values starting with something else?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try using below-mentioned query.

Consider table name as #a and column name as colA.

```
Update #a set colA = case when len(ltrim(rtrim(cola)))<=3 then colA else right(colA, len(ltrim(rtrim(colA)))-3) end

Select * from #a
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical method is:

```
(case when columnA like '800%' then substring(columnA, 4, 6) else columnA) as new_columnA
```

Note:  This preserves values when the value does not start with `800`.  And `substring()` might be spelled `substr()` in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data values are stored as numbers, I ended up treating it like a math problem.

```
 BEGIN TRAN
 SET XACT_ABORT ON
 UPDATE sometable
 SET ColumnA = ColumnA - 800000000
 WHERE ColumnA LIKE '8006%'
```

It is not sophisticated but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET ColumnA = SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 4, LEN(ColumnA))
WHERE LEN(ColumnA) = 9 AND ColumnA LIKE '800%'
```

A mass update would look like this with the information you have provided. Update ColumnA and take the entire value starting at the 4th character. Only do this when the length of ColumnA is equal to 9 and is prefixed with 800.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the records by checking the string length which are exactly 9 digits and which starts with characters '800'. Same can be achieved with help of LEFT/RIGHT function.

```
UPDATE  data_table
SET     columnA = right(columnA,6)
WHERE   LEN(columnA) = 9 AND left(columnA,3) = '800' 

Note: Consider "data_table" as your actual table and "columnA" as the column you want to update.
```

Comment: While this code might answer the OP's question, you could make your answer much better by appending an explanation on how your code solves the problem